# part match url string with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I am looking to get the url using

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

but how do I get the first part of the string between the fist two / /

so if my url is

www.mysite.com/blog/august/2013

I want to get 'blog'

if it is www.mysite.com/aboutme/information

I would like to get 'aboutme'

any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: can you ensure you will always get that kind of pathname?

Comment: no it could be contact-us, home or anything else.

Answer (score 7):

`"www.mysite.com/aboutme/information".split("/")[1]`

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure if the link will be in that format you could use

```
var arrPathName = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var firstPathItem = '';

if(arrPathName.length > 1) {
    firstPathItem = arrPathName[1];
}

// firstPathItem would be 'blog' in the case of 'www.mysite.com/blog/august/2013'
// If the path is none existent (www.mysite.com) it will be empty
console.log(firstPathItem);
```